# Not able to serve static file for dynamic html pages using handlebars hapi js and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, hapi.js

I am trying to serve html  file using hapi and handlebars template engine i am not able to serve the static file required for html rendering like css ,images and js when i make the url dynamic for accepting some parameters from users for dynamic html file rendering

This code was able to serve the static files required for html all the css and images loaded properly

```js
const server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({
    port: 3000,
    host: 'localhost'
}); 
server.register(require('vision'),(err)=>{
    Hoek.assert(!err, err);
    server.views({
        engines:{
            'html': {
                module: require('handlebars'),
                isCached: false // engine specific
            }
            

        },
        relativeTo:__dirname,
        path:'./templates'
        
    });
});
//inert module for serving files
server.register({  
    register: require('inert')
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err
  
    
  })
  //path for  the resources
  server.route({  
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{file*}',
    handler: {
      directory: { 
        
        
        path:'./templates'
      }
    }
  })
  //static route for serving html
  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/handlebars',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        
        reply.view('index');
    }
});
```

but when i change the static url to serve dynamic html file based on user parameter it only serves the html file but not able to serve iamges,js and css

above code remain same  only thing changed is

```js
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/handlebars/{timername}',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        
         hbtimername=encodeURIComponent(request.params.timername);
        
        reply.view(hbtimername);
    }
});
```

vs code gives the following error log
Error: No view engine found for file: trans.gif
    at internals.Manager._prepare (C:\Users\quality_digital_2\Schedulerapi\Schedulerapi\node_modules\vision\lib\manager.js:318:30)
    at Object.internals.prepare (C:\Users\quality_digital_2\Schedulerapi\Schedulerapi\node_modules\vision\lib\manager.js:599:13)
    at internals.Response._processPrepare

and chrome dev console shows the follwing logs
GET http://localhost:3000/handlebars/trans.gif 500 (Internal Server Error)

is i am doing anything wrong with file routing i am new to handlebars i tried searching and also tried to do changes in the routing but no luck